# Dynamic PDFs and Android default browser

Tags: c#, android

I am working on delivering PDF files that are generated on demand to users of mobile devices.  I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 and I generate the PDF using the Report Viewer local report export as PDF.

This gives me the raw byte[] of PDF content.

I then return it using:

return File( pdf , mimeType , "FileName.pdf" );

Note, I have tried it with and without the "FileName.pdf" default name for saving the file.

It works great in desktop browsers and iPhones.  I have tested with the WP 7 emulator and it seems like it would work if it could just read PDFs (it prompts for the proper file name to save it).

Android seems to be complaining, however.

I have tested on Droid-X and Droid devices and it always shows " Download unsuccessful" in the browser download results.  On Opera Mini it prompted to save the file (when using the return method that included the file name) and the PDF opened fine after it was saved on the device.

I can return PDF files that already exist on disk just fine with: File( "~/filename.pdf" , "application/pdf" ); so it seems to just be a problem with dynamic PDFs.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before?

Comment: Can you verify that you are actually setting the mime type in the same way in the dynamic case?  Can you snoop the traffic or otherwise dump the headers to compare?

Comment: The mime type IS getting set to application/pdf.  I discovered what appeared to be happening is that immediately after the POST occurred for the resource, the Android device (even does it with the emulator in the SDK) does an immediate GET for the same resource.  The HTTP POST was successful, but the GET resulted in a 404 (because I was just responding to POSTs).  I don't know why it requested it twice (with different methods each time).  After I enabled HTTP GETs then it DID work correctly and didn't do two requests.  I haven't figured out the double requests yet, but I did make progress.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Firefox and Opera Mobile work, but not the native DroidX browser. BTW, dynamic jpeg images work fine. I'm using HTTPS, which seems to make things worse. I have been able to load static PDF files over HTTP. The MIME type is correct. Seems like a common problem with Android users from what I've seen on the Android forums.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tested on Droid-X and Droid devices and it always shows " Download unsuccessful" in the browser download results.

AFAIK, that means either that the HTTP request failed or that the MIME type was not one for which there is an `ACTION_VIEW` activity registered. Bear in mind that the DROID did not ship with a PDF viewer, and I forget if the DROID X did or not.

I agree with Chris, in that it feels like the problem is an invalid MIME type. Consider using `curl` or a browser plugin to inspect your HTTP response headers and confirm that, indeed, `application/pdf` is being returned as the MIME type.

If that does not help, and you can supply us with a URL to test, that would help as well.

Comment: The URL is not accessible from the public Internet, but as I mentioned in my comments above, the MIME type was correct but it was executing a POST, followed immediately by the GET and displaying the response only for the GET (which was a 404, so no content to display).

Answer (score 0):

I see this questions id from years ago, but if you just want to display the pdf, you can embed your pdf URL in google doc viewer, and then reference that URL, then it should open on android browsers.

However, this will only work if your URL is publicly accessible.